# Mockito.when() clause for java streams

Tags: java, java-8, mockito, java-stream, junit4

I would like to know how can I write `when()` clause for below code

```
Optional<Adapter> adapterOp = adapters.stream()
    .filter(adapter -> adapter
    .getName.equals(someName)).findFirst();
```

Comment: don't, just provide a list with the content you need. also, make sure the code you write is compilable. The code you posted here isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) is used for immediate data sequence processing, not as a *source* for further processing.

If you need to somehow operate with the Stream during the unit testing, I'd stick with the following rules:

1. Mock/fake a `List<T>` from which is `Stream<T>` created or provide its final output.
2. Mock/fake the `@FunctionalInterfaces` used in the Stream itself (`Predicate`, `Function`...) if passed through the class and/or methods.
3. Unit test the processing itself separately.

If you insist on mocking Stream using Mockito, you have to know that Stream is a fluent interface that is based on the builder design pattern - in nutshell, each method returns the same type `Stream<T>`. It means that you have to mock each method of the chain separately and return a new instance of a mocked `Stream<T>` instance.